Recently ended recent tags experiment
In September, we tested a Recent Tags feature on Stack Overflow, this was a part of experiment three, mentioned on this post. It ran from September 3rd to October 1st. This experiment showed the last five tags a user saw in a post on the left-hand sidebar. After concluding the experiment, we found that some users interacted with it, but ultimately did not see a significant change in users watching tags.
To that end, the experiment was concluded, and the feature has been removed from the left nav.

The problem that I had with the recent tags list is that just a singular question could replace all five recent tags; it just became a "last viewed question's tags" list. If the list was instead populated based on some sort of "recent tags you've been interacting with frequently", I'd see it being more useful (the specifics, I'm not sure of).
For example, viewing multiple posts with c# and unity-game-engine, and then clicking one question with just c# but 4 other tags would immediately remove unity-game-engine from the recent tags list. If the list was instead smart enough to recognize that "the last 10 questions had this tag, maybe we should keep displaying it", I would've used it a lot more.


After concluding the experiment, we found that some users interacted with it, but ultimately did not see a significant change in users watching tags.

Basing the performance of the recent tag list on tags watched seems strange to me. Not only are they're completely separate features, the recent tag list (sort of) competes with the watched tag list. I'd assume that interactions would be a lot more important than clicking a tag, then going to the complete opposite corner of the screen to watch it.

More fundamentally, there obviously are no good solutions to "we had a moronic KPI foisted upon us by bean counters who understand nothing about the site."

I'd imagine an idea from the original design woulda been more effective at encouraging users to watch tags


I was admiring this piece of art that I'm definitely hanging on the wall in the toilet, and then my eye fell on "Pickles". I don't know what it is, but I need it.


After concluding the experiment, we found that some users interacted
with it, but ultimately did not see a significant change in users
watching tags.

Shocker. Honestly if anything new was added to the left sidebar I'm sure was lost on many users that have been trained and conditioned to completely ignore that area of the page. It is unclear where the thought train made the connection between "viewing most recent question's tags" and "users modifying their watched tags" as a success metric.
If we want to view and edit our watched tags, etc, there's already the specific section for that all the way over on the opposite side of the screen in the right sidebar.

I don't even see it, since I keep the left panel collapsed. Given that... I don't need all that noise.
